# How can I draw a big image in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a floor for a top down style game, where I used to use pictureboxes

I was told that instead of using a Picturebox, I should be using the `Graphics.DrawImage();` method, which seems to slightly help but still is very laggy.

My paint function looks like this to draw the background looks like this:

How should I make the drawing less laggy? The image is 2256 by 1504

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawImage(PeanutToTheDungeon.Properties.Resources.tutorialFloor, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: It seems you know how to draw a big image in WinForms already. What are you asking us?

Comment: I'm asking if anybody knows how to make it lag less, I am drawing a very big image and it lags everytime I run the app.

Comment: Then you should ask that in the question itself. But you should also provide the code so that we can replicate it and see the lag - then we can test our solution before posting. The code you've posted doesn't show that.

Comment: Right, I've copied your code pretty much exactly and I have nothing that I would call lag. Everything rendered instantly for me. Can you please explain what you mean by lag and how we are to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points that I would make here.

Firstly, DO NOT use `Properties.Resources` like that. Every time you use a property of that object, the data for that resource gets extracted from the assembly. That means that you are creating a new `Image` object every time the `Paint` event is raised, which is often. You should use that resource property once and once only, assign the value to a field and then use that field repeatedly. That means that you will save the time of extracting that data and creating the `Image` object every time.

The second point may or may not be applicable but, if you are forcing the `Paint` event to be raised by calling `Invalidate` or `Refresh` then you need to make sure that you are invalidating the minimum area possible. If you call `Refresh` or `Invalidate` with no argument then you are invalidating the whole for, which means that the whole form will be repainted. The repainting of pixels on screen is actually the slow part of the process, so that's the part that you need to keep to a minimum. That means that, when something changes on your game board, you need to calculate the smallest area possible that will contain all the possible changes and specify that when calling `Invalidate`. That will reduce the amount of repainting and speed up the process.

Note that you don't need to change your drawing code. You always DRAW everything, then the system will PAINT the part of the form that you previously invalidated.

Comment: After trying jmcilhinney's answer, by changing Properties.Resources to a single field and reusing it, instead of getting the image everytime, fixed all the lag.

Comment: Setting `InterpolationMode` to `NearestNeighbor` and `CompositionQuality` to `HighSpeed` are also possible optimization options.